# How to implement online construction of Convex Hull in O(n^2) time?

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

Online construction as in, getting the input points one by one and finding the hull for the points given till that time.

I can do this with Graham scan in `O(n * nlogn)`, or `O(n^2 logn)`. But I'm looking for an `O(n^2)` solution.

I've read of Melkman's `O(n)` algorithm. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: the edit on Apr 30 '19 is incorrect; it should have remained "O(n * n log n)", not "O(n log n)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a slight modification of Graham scan. Recall that Graham scan for static convex hull takes O(N lg N) only because of the need to sort the points by angle at the beginning. The actual stack manipulations afterward take only O(N).

Hence, we maintain a linked list of all the points that we maintain to be sorted by angle. Each additional point can be inserted in the correct position in O(N) time. Afterwards, the stack manipulation part of Graham can still be done in O(N) time.

Hence, since there are N insertions with O(N) work per insertion, this takes O(N^2) time to print all the incremental convex hulls.

Comment: This was one of my first questions on S/O, and I never really did get back to solving it. Great answer! I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The first question that came into my mind that, why do you need an `O(n^2)` solution when you already know a solution which computes the convex hull in `O(nlogn)`. Anyway, you can trivially solve the problem with `O(n^3)` solution, however, I cannot remember of any algorithm which computes the convex hull in `O(n^2)`.

If you are taking [QuickHull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull) algorithm to compute convex hull, then in the **worst case**, this will give you the following recurrence.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)
```

Which resolves to `O(n^2)` complexity. However, in the usual case, you will still get the complexity of `O(nlogn)`.

Another algorithm is [Jarvis March and Gift-Wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm), which does compute the convex hull in `O(nh)` where `n` is the input size (all the points in the convex hull) and `h` is the output size (i.e. all the edges that bounds the convex hull).

In this Jarvis March algorithm, the **worst case** complexity can run into `O(n^2)` as well when all the points in the convex hull are in the boundary. Hence in the worst case, you will find an `O(n^2)` solution. However, in the usual case, it computes the convex hull in `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: the question was asking about [**online** convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#On-line_and_dynamic_convex_hull_problems), so this answer is missing the point.